# Ruby version with rbenv keeps slipping back to 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I installed rbenv and Ruby 1.9.3-p362 following all the caveats in the installation, then set `rbenv global 1.9.3-p362` and can see 1.9.3 when running `ruby -v`. But, everytime I quit terminal and reopen a session, `ruby -v` goes back to 1.8.7.

rbenv is still in my path so I don't know what could be going wrong.

Any thoughts?

---

UPDATES:

Info as requested:

```
which ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
echo $PATH: /Users/<username>/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Please append the output of `which ruby` and `echo $PATH` to your question.

Comment: Just added those details for you

Comment: Try two things: `rbenv shell --unset` followed by `rbenv global 1.9.3-p372` and see if `which ruby` is pointing to the right version. If not, try `find ~ -name .ruby-version -type f` to see if any folders have a "local" setting that forces the Ruby version. If so, use `find ~ -name .ruby-version -type f -exec rm {} \;` to clear them out.

Comment: Just tried these. `rbenv shell --unset` said `rbenv: no such command 'shell'`. I searched for all the .ruby-version files and the only two present are within the two project directories I have on this machine.  So i'm really not sure what to do! :-)

Comment: Any ideas? Really need to get this up and running consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a FYI, Ruby 1.9.3-p362 was replaced by p374 due to bugs, so you should either upgrade to p374 or downgrade to p327.

If you installed the "ruby-build" plugin you can tell rbenv how to find the p374 version by doing:

```
cd ~/.rbenv
git pull
cd plugins/ruby-build/
git pull
rbenv install 1.9.3-p374
```

This will reload all the gems for p362 into your p374:

```
rbenv global 1.9.3-p362
gem list | awk '{print $1}' > ~/.rbenv/gem_list
rbenv global 1.9.3-p374
xargs gem install < ~/.rbenv/gem_list
```

It'll churn away and spit out lots of gem installation verbiage, then you should be ready to delete p362 using:

```
rbenv uninstall 1.9.3-p362
```

Comment: Just updating to Ruby 1.9.3-p374 and i'll report back.

Comment: Updated to 1.9.3-p374 and it makes no difference. rbenv global is fine but ruby-v keeps reporting 1.8.7

Comment: Any ideas? Really need to get this up and running consistently.